# Getting currently active menu title with KnpMenuBundle

Tags: symfony, knpmenubundle

How getting currently active menu title with KnpMenuBundle ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the moment, I use the `twig variable` :

```
{{ knp_menu_get_current_item('leftsidebar').name }}
```

`leftsidebar` it's name of the service of my menu :)